# How to make a model suffer from underfitting

Tags: deep-learning, overfitting

I would like to show an example of my model when it is overfitting, and when it is underfitting. Now overfitting is pretty straight forward, just train on small data, and the model will remember the data. But how do I show example of underfitting? I have a couple of suggestions:

1. lowering the learning rate, but I do not think this is really underfitting. This is just slow learn model.
2. add a dropout layer with 0.99, so that the network could not learn well enough.
3. maybe change the architecture somehow that it will be harder to learn.

I think (2) is the best option, what do you guys think?

My model:

```
conv2d (kernel=5,feature_maps=20)
batch_normalization
ReLU
Flatten()
FullyConnected(11,500->10)
Softmax
```

and the task it to label MNIST hand written.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to simply decrease the complexity of your model so that it has less parameters and has a harder type capturing all patterns in the data. You could for example decrease the number of filters in your convolutional layer and decrease the number of neurons in the fully connected layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to underfit is to reduce the complexity of the model so the model is unable to learn patterns in the training data.

Here are a couple of options:

- Reduce the number of layers
- Reduce the size of the layers
- Use a linear activation function

Answer (score 0):

Underfitting means that you have failed to capture features that influence the outcome, in your case, the digit that is drawn in an image. The ultimate in failing to capture features is to capture no features and always predict the prior probability of $\sim 1/10$ for each number (I recall there being slight imbalance in the $60000$ standard training images). This is the baseline performance, and it corresponds to a neural network with zero features and zero hidden layers, essentially an intercept-only (multinomial) logistic regression, and it is analogous to a linear regression with $R^2=0$.

You might be tempted to use a model that has stronger performance, but this is the most underfitted a model can be, and I would expect it to be useful for the teaching purposes you have in mind.

Comment: thank you both! i chose to show the same trainig for a model with 1 filter sized 3x3. so now the accuracy is only 76% unlike 99% accuracy at the original model.